# PUT blob with Blob Service API in Postman - Authorization header

Tags: api, azure, azure-blob-storage

I need help constructing the Authorization header to PUT a block blob.

```
PUT\n\n\n11\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:Sat, 25 Feb 2017 22:20:13 GMT\nx-ms-version:2015-02-21\n/myaccountname/mycontainername/blob.txt\n
```

I take this, UTF 8 encode it.  Then I take my access key in my Azure account and HMAC sha256 this UTF 8 encoded string with the key.  Then I output that in base64.  Let's call this output string.

My authorization header looks like this: SharedKey myaccountname:output string

It is not working.

The header in Postman also has x-ms-blob-type, x-ms-date, x-ms-version, Content-Length, and Authorization.  The body for now says hello world.

Can anyone help me make this successful request in Postman?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
    <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:cdeb9a5e-0001-0029-5fb5-8f7995000000
Time:2017-02-25T22:22:32.0300016Z</Message>
    <AuthenticationErrorDetail>The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'jiJtirohvi1syXulqkPKESnmQEJI4GpDU5JBn7BM/xY=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'PUT


11

text/plain;charset=UTF-8






x-ms-date:Sat, 25 Feb 2017 22:20:13 GMT
x-ms-version:2015-02-21
/myaccountname/mycontainername/blob.txt'.</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

EDIT:

First, I want to thank you and everyone who responded.  I truly truly appreciate it.  I have one last question and then I think I'll be set!!  I'm not using that code - I'm doing this all by hand.  If I have my key: `X2iiy6v47j1jZZH5555555555zzQRrIAdxxVs55555555555av8uBUNGcBMotmS7tDqas14gU5O/w==` changed slightly for anonymity - do I decode it: using an online base64decoder.  Then, when I have my string which now looks like this: `PUT\n\n\n11\n\ntext/plain;charset=UTF-8\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:Mon, 27 Feb 2017 21:53:13 GMT\nx-ms-version:2015-02-21\n/myaccount/mycontainer/blob.txt\n` so I run this in `https://mothereff.in/utf-8` and then use this in HMAC with my decoded key: `https://www.liavaag.org/English/SHA-Generator/HMAC/` - using sha256 and base64 at the end.

Is that how I get the correct string to put here?: `SharedKey myaccount:<string here>`

Comment: With the tool that you mentioned to generated the code doesn't match signature due to the "\n" charaters. I wrote an [online tool](https://onlineencrypt.herokuapp.com/) to generate  signature. I also updated the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's an issue with how you're specifying `StringToSign` here:

> PUT\n\n\n11\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:Sat,
>   25 Feb 2017 22:20:13
>   GMT\nx-ms-version:2015-02-21\n/myaccountname/mycontainername/blob.txt\n

If you notice the error message returned from the server, string to sign by server is different than yours and the difference is that the server is using `Content-Type` (`text/plain;charset=UTF-8`) in signature calculation while you're not. Please include this content type in your code and things should work just fine.

Here's the sample code (partial only) I used:

```
        var requestMethod = "PUT";
        var urlPath = "test" + "/" + "myblob.txt";
        var storageServiceVersion = "2015-12-11";
        var date = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var blobType = "BlockBlob";
        var contentBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World");
        var canonicalizedResource = "/" + accountName + "/" + urlPath;
        var canonicalizedHeaders = "x-ms-blob-type:" + blobType + "\nx-ms-date:" + date + "\nx-ms-version:" + storageServiceVersion + "\n";
        var stringToSign = requestMethod + "\n" +
            "\n" + //Content Encoding
            "\n" + //Content Language
            "11\n" + //Content Length
            "\n" + //Content MD5
            "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" + "\n" + //Content Type
            "\n" + //Date
            "\n" + //If - Modified - Since
            "\n" + //If - Match
            "\n" + //If - None - Match
            "\n" + //If - Unmodified - Since
            "\n" + //Range +
           canonicalizedHeaders +
           canonicalizedResource;
        string authorizationHeader = GenerateSharedKey(stringToSign, accountKey, accountName);


    private static string GenerateSharedKey(string stringToSign, string key, string account)
    {
        string signature;
        var unicodeKey = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
        using (var hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256(unicodeKey))
        {
            var dataToHmac = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign);
            signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha256.ComputeHash(dataToHmac));
        }
        return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0} {1}:{2}", "SharedKey", account, signature);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message, it indicates that authorization signature is incorrect.

If the Content-Type `"text/plain; charset=UTF-8"` is not included in the header, please add it in the stringTosign and postman.

When we try to get the signature, we need to make sure the `length of the blob.txt` matches the `Content length` in the stringTosign. That means request body length should match the content length in the stringTosign.

I test it with Postman, it works correctly. We can get the signature with the code in another [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829911/azure-rest-api-put-blob?answertab=active#tab-top). The following is my detail steps

1. Add the following header

[image]

2. Add the request body (example: Hello World)

[image]

3. Send the put blob request.

[image]

**Update :**

Please have a try to use the [online tool](https://onlineencrypt.herokuapp.com/) to generate signature for test.