# Query Blob storage with multiple Tags in where not working

Tags: postman, azure-blob-storage

I am able to successfully get Blobs from storage via postman filtering on 1 Tag.  When I expand the GET call to include multiple Tags I get the below error in AuthenticationerrorDetail

```
    <AuthenticationErrorDetail>The MAC signature found in the HTTP request &apos;XXXXXXXXXXtGSue862ZtEYGEM2fn+3a94=&apos; is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: &apos;GET

x-ms-date:Thu, 26 May 2022 18:12:06 GMT
x-ms-version:2020-08-04
/XXXXXXXXX/
comp:blobs
where:@container=&apos;{{log-container-name}}&apos; AND &quot;RequestMethod&quot;=&apos;PATCH&apos; AND &quot;OperationId&quot;=&apos;{{correlation-id}}&apos;&apos;.</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
```

My URL is: `https://{{storage-account-name}}.blob.core.windows.net?comp=blobs&where=%40container%3D%27%7B%7Blog-container-name%7D%7D%27%20AND%20%22RequestMethod%22%3D%27PATCH%27%20AND%20%22OperationId%22%3D%27%7B%7Bcorrelation-id%7D%7D%27`

My Pre-req

```
const accessKey = pm.environment.get('storage-account-access-key');
const accountName = pm.environment.get('storage-account-name');
const containerName = pm.environment.get('log-container-name');
const correlationId = pm.environment.get('correlation-id');

const queryDate = new Date().toGMTString();
const method = pm.request.method;
const stringToSign = method + '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:' + queryDate + '\nx-ms-version:2020-08-04\n/' + accountName + '/\ncomp:blobs\nwhere:@container=\'' + containerName + '\' AND "RequestMethod"=\'' + 'PATCH' + '\'' + '\' AMD "OperationalId"=\'' + correlationId + '\'';
var signature = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(stringToSign,  CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(accessKey)));
var authorizationToken = 'SharedKey ' + accountName + ':' + signature;
```

I am guessing I have a simple syntax error in my stringToSign but I cannot see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Shared Key format for 2009-09-19 and later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#shared-key-format-for-2009-09-19-and-later)

> Convert all parameter names to lowercase.
>
> **Sort the query parameters lexicographically by parameter name, in ascending order.**
>
> URL-decode each query parameter name and value.
>
> Include a new-line character (\n) before each name-value pair.
>
> Append each query parameter name and value to the string in the
> following format, making sure to include the colon (:) between the
> name and the value:
>
> `parameter-name:parameter-value`
>
> If a query parameter has more than one value, `sort all values lexicographically`, then include them in a `comma-separated list`:

Note that fields included in the string-to-sign must be URL-decoded.

Also check this and compare all the construction formats [put-blob-with-blob-service-api-in-postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462746/put-blob-with-blob-service-api-in-postman-authorization-header)

Reference: [To encode the Shared Key signature string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#blob-queue-and-file-services-shared-key-authorization)