# Azure BLOB storage REST call from C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I am trying to communicate with my Container on Azure Blob Storage through a console application. I cannot use the SDK hence REST is my only option. Language is C# with .NET 4.5.2.

I have tried these two codes and both return the same error

[Azure rest API put blob On StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829911/azure-rest-api-put-blob)

[Azure Blob Storage Part 5(Non-StackOverflow)](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/platform-as-a-service/azure-blob-storage-part-5-blob-storage-rest-api/)

The error that I receive is 400 Bad Request
[image: Error from my console application]

Has anybody else faced the same issue and successfully resolved it?

I have added a CORS rule with (*) for almost everything

The code is an exact duplicate of the two links hence I am not adding it here.

```
    class Program
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        UploadBlobWithRestAPI();
    }

    public static void UploadBlobWithRestAPI()
    {

        string storageKey = "ffFJwPXTqyYvRoubNQEti/aQUUMwn41BG3KDtl/yGpG4DR1eKaHRq6Bhbw==";
        string storageAccount = "xyz";
        string containerName = "notes";
        string blobName = "test567";

        string method = "PUT";
        string sampleContent = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla id euismod urna. Maecenas scelerisque dolor purus, sed ullamcorper ipsum lobortis non. Nulla est justo, sodales at venenatis a, faucibus";
        int contentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(sampleContent);

        string requestUri = $"https://xyz.blob.core.windows.net/notes/test567";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);

        string now = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R");

        request.Method = method;
        request.ContentType = "text/plain; charset=UTF-8";
        request.ContentLength = contentLength;

        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2018-01-11");
        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", now);
        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", AuthorizationHeader2(method, now, request, storageAccount, storageKey, containerName, blobName));

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sampleContent), 0, contentLength);
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(resp.StatusCode.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }

    public static string AuthorizationHeader2(string method, string now, HttpWebRequest request, string storageAccount, 
        string storageKey, string containerName, string blobName)
    {

        string headerResource = $"x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:"+ DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R") +"\nx-ms-version:2018-01-11";
        string urlResource = "/xyz/notes/test567";
        string stringToSign =  method + "\n\n\n" + request.ContentLength + 
            "\n\n" + request.ContentType +"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" + headerResource + "\n" + urlResource;


        HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(storageKey));
        string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));

        String AuthorizationHeader = String.Format("{0} {1}:{2}", "SharedKey", storageAccount, signature);
        return AuthorizationHeader;
    }


}
```

Comment: Is there an error code? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-error-codes)

Comment: Read [ask] and show the relevant code.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: No, because it throws an exception before the response object can be initialized 
    using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())

Comment: Please add `request.Headers.Add("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");` and see if that solves the problem. You're missing this required header in your request.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, help much appreciated but unfortunately it is already there, I have edited the question to add my code  and if you look at the two functions(copied from online resource)
AuthorizationHeader2 and AuthorizationHeader, both functions include this header.

Comment: May I ask you to edit your question and include only the relevant code. Right now there are too many methods in there. If you're facing issues with uploading blob, then please include code related to that only and remove all the unnecessary code. It will become easier to see what's going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. You're using an invalid service version. Latest Storage Service REST API version is `2017-04-17` and not `2018-01-11`. Once you change that, you will not get 400 error (but you will get 403 error).
2. In your `headerResource`, you are generating a new date/time value which would be different than the date/time value in your `x-ms-date` header. Because of this you will get 403 error. So essentially your code would be:

   ```
       string headerResource = $"x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:" + now + "\nx-ms-version:2017-04-17";
   ```

I made these two fixes and after that I was able to upload the data.

Here's the complete code:

```
    public static void UploadBlobWithRestAPI()
    {

        string storageKey = "ffFJwPXTqyYvRoubNQEti/aQUUMwn41BG3KDtl/yGpG4DR1eKaHRq6Bhbw==";
        string storageAccount = "xyz";
        string containerName = "notes";
        string blobName = "test567";

        string method = "PUT";
        string sampleContent = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla id euismod urna. Maecenas scelerisque dolor purus, sed ullamcorper ipsum lobortis non. Nulla est justo, sodales at venenatis a, faucibus";
        int contentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(sampleContent);

        string requestUri = $"https://xyz.blob.core.windows.net/notes/test567";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);

        string now = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R");

        request.Method = method;
        request.ContentType = "text/plain; charset=UTF-8";
        request.ContentLength = contentLength;

        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2017-04-17");
        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", now);
        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", AuthorizationHeader2(method, now, request, storageAccount, storageKey, containerName, blobName));

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sampleContent), 0, contentLength);
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(resp.StatusCode.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }

    public static string AuthorizationHeader2(string method, string now, HttpWebRequest request, string storageAccount,
        string storageKey, string containerName, string blobName)
    {

        string headerResource = $"x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:" + now + "\nx-ms-version:2017-04-17";
        string urlResource = "/xyz/notes/test567";
        string stringToSign = method + "\n\n\n" + request.ContentLength +
            "\n\n" + request.ContentType + "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" + headerResource + "\n" + urlResource;


        HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(storageKey));
        string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));

        String AuthorizationHeader = String.Format("{0} {1}:{2}", "SharedKey", storageAccount, signature);
        return AuthorizationHeader;
    }
```