# Azure Blob Service REST API - Error: read ECONNRESET

Tags: node.js, azure, http, azure-blob-storage

#### The goal and where I got so far

I'm trying to use the Azurue Storage Blob Services REST API with Node.JS. So far I managed to make successful requests for the `List Containers` and `Get Blob Services Properties` operations. Now I'm trying `Put Blob` based on [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob) from MS.

I've had 400 and 403 errors and searched for similar questions, even when it was [a question on C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48202964/azure-blob-storage-rest-call-from-c-sharp?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [on R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44519413/azure-put-blob-authentication-fails-in-r) instead of Node.JS, reading it helped me understand what I might be doing wrong and change my code. In that case, it was the signature and its Canonicalized Resource and Canonicalized Headers that lack clearer documentation.

#### The problem

When I thought I fixed the signature problem (after all the response stopped telling me that that was the problem) and now I don't have those errors anymore, all that happens is: I make the request and it freezes for a while; after some time I receive the message:

```
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27)
Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

From [this question on a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/how-do-i-debug-error-econnreset-in-node-js#17637900) I learned that it's an interrupted connection on the other side of the TCP. So it's probably not the signature anymore but I have no idea what it is. Do I need to make another type of request before a `Put Blob`?

I tried changing the signature, also tried creating a a local .txt file to be uploaded, and tried uploading a simple string from a variable.
I'm not sure where the data should come from to be uploaded.

I think my main problem is that for the other errors and issues I've had, I was given some information to (eventually and after a lot of reading) solve it; but now I don't even get a Status 200 anymore.

#### The code

My function to create a signature:

```
/**
   * Authorization using HMAC SHA 256.
   * @param {String} VERB - Request method to be used (GET, PUT).
   * @param {String} strTime - Time of the request, in RFC 1123 Format.
   * @param {String} path - Path of the URL, containing the name of the
   * container and the query parameters.
   */
  create_signature(VERB, strTime, uri, content) {
    VERB = VERB.toUpperCase();

    // removing first slash
    uri = uri.replace("/","");
    
    // separating '/container/blob?q=query&q=query' into 'container/blob' and 'q=query&q=query'
    var [path, query] = uri.split("?");
    // changing 'q=query&q=query' to 'q:query\nq:query' if '?' is included
    query = query ? query.replace(/\=/g,":").replace(/\&/g,"\n") : '';
    // without the '?' char the separation is '/container/blob' and ''
    
    const content_type = "text/plain; charset=UTF-8";
    const content_length = content.length.toString();
    
    let strToSign = VERB + "\n" + // VERB
      "\n" +                      // Content-Encoding
      "\n" +                      // Content-Language
      content_length + "\n" +     // Content-Length
      "\n" +                      // Content-MD5
      content_type + "\n" +         // Content-Type
      "\n" +                      // Date
      "\n" +                      // If-Modified-Since
      "\n" +                      // If-Match
      "\n" +                      // If-None-Match
      "\n" +                      // If-Unmodified-Since
      "\n" +                      // Range
      // CanonicalizedHeaders
      `x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob` + "\n" +
      `x-ms-date:${strTime}` + "\n" + 
      `x-ms-version:${this.version}` + "\n" +
      // CanonicalizedResource
      `/${this.account_name}/${path}`;

    console.log(strToSign);
    // strToSign = strToSign.toLowerCase();
    // strToSign = encodeURIComponent(strToSign);

    // generating secret from account key
    var secret = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(this.account_key);
    // encrypting the signature
    var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(strToSign, secret);
    var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
    var auth_sig = `SharedKey ${this.account_name}:` + hashInBase64;

    return auth_sig;
  }
```

To make a request using the http module:

```
// making the request using the http module:
  put_blob(container_name, filename) {
    const time_UTC_str = new Date().toUTCString();
    var path = `/${container_name}/${filename}`;

    const obj = "hello world";

    const signature = this.create_signature('PUT', time_UTC_str, path, obj);


    const req_params = {
      method: 'PUT',
      hostname: this.hostname,
      path: path,
      headers: {
        'Authorization': signature,
        'x-ms-date': time_UTC_str,
        'x-ms-version': this.version,
        'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob',
        'Content-Length': obj.length.toString(),
        'Content-Type': "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
      }
    }

    let req = http.request(req_params, this.res_handler);
    req.end();
  }
```

The response handler function:

```
  /**
 * Callback function that handles and parses the responses, 
 * including how the search results will be processed.
 * @param {object} res - response from request
 */
  res_handler = function (res) {

    let body = '';
    // storing body
    res.on('data', (dat) => {
      body += dat;
    });

    // when signaling 'end' flag
    res.on('end', () => {
      // parsing response
      if (!res.complete) {
        console.error('The connection was terminated while the message was still being sent');
      } else {
        // console.log(res);
        console.log(`Status: ${res.statusCode} - ${res.statusMessage}`);
      }
      console.log('Response: ' + body);
      
    });

    // handling errors
    res.on('error', (err) => {
      console.error(`Error ${err.statusCode}: ${err.statusMessage}`);
    });

  };
```

> *PS: Should I try another cloud service or are they all complicated and bad documented?*

Answer (score 3):

I had forgotten to use `req.write()` to actually write the data. I'm embarrassed but I will explain what happenned in case someone has a similar problem.

As I explained before, that error comes from an interruption on the connection from the other side, like a timeout for inactivity. So it kept waiting for me to write data to the request, and because I didn't, it eventually stopped waiting, thus returning that error.

Turns out it had nothing to do with Azure or Blob Services, I just didn't send anything to be uploaded. And it took me some time to realize that but in the process I really learned a lot by researching about this.

The last lines of the `put_blob()` method now look like this:

```
let req = http.request(req_params, this.res_handler);
req.write(obj);    // it was missing this! 
req.end();
```

Now I (hopefully) will **never** forget to write data on a PUT request.