# Adding Pom dependency for azure blob changes my REST API response from JSON to XML

Tags: azure, rest, azure-blob-storage

I have a web application with REST API and its working fine returning JSON response and no issues at all.

Now I am trying to add azure blob service to upload blob files to my azure account.

As soon as I add maven dependency for azure blob, my existing REST API started returning XML response breaking my whole application.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
            <version>12.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Has anybody encountered this issue? Removing this dependency fixes the problem but then I wont be able to connect to Azure cloud.

Comment: Hi, @vs14, does my reply help? If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use Java SDK even though you have added the dependency?

If you still want to use REST API like [PUT BLOB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob), you could set `Content-Type` as `application/json`. When using [shared key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key) to access, you also need to add Content-Type to "stringToSign". You could refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41832964/13308381) with C#.

> StringToSign = VERB + "\n" +
> Content-Encoding + "\n" +
> Content-Language + "\n" +
> Content-Length + "\n" +
> Content-MD5 + "\n" +
> **Content-Type + "\n" +**
> Date + "\n" +
> If-Modified-Since + "\n" +
> If-Match + "\n" +
> If-None-Match + "\n" +
> If-Unmodified-Since + "\n" +
> Range + "\n" +
> CanonicalizedHeaders +
> CanonicalizedResource;

---

Demo about uploading local file to blob with [SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/azure-storage-blob_12.10.0/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob#azure-storage-blob-client-library-for-java):

```
String accountName = "";
String accountKey = "";
StorageSharedKeyCredential credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
String endpoint = String.format(Locale.ROOT, "https://%s.blob.core.windows.net", accountName);

BlobServiceClient storageClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().endpoint(endpoint).credential(credential).buildClient();
BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("mycontainer");
BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.getBlobClient("myblockblob");
blobClient.uploadFromFile("local-file.jpg");
```